# Scala partial function composition performance

Tags: scala, partial-functions

Is there any difference in the performance of a partial function defined as

```
val matches = {
   case Match(x,y) => ...
   case AnotherMatch(x,y,z) => ...
   case x:YetAnother => ...
}
```

and one defined as below?

```
val match1 = {
   case Match(x,y) => ... 
}
val match2 = {
   case AnotherMatch(x,y,z) => ...
}
val match3 = {
   case x:YetAnother => ...
}
val matches = match1 orElse match2 orElse match3
```

Comment: Yes. Most of the time it's likely to be negligible, though, and if the latter approach in any way makes your code more readable or maintainable, you should use it, and only optimize when you've confirmed that the performance is a real issue in your application.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is about a factor of 2 if the matches are

```
Some(x: Int) if x > 0 => x
Some(x: Int) if x < 0 => -x
None => 0
```

So it can be significant in a tight loop, but often won't be.